# Does a orthogonal basis for the span of $S$ always have the same dimension as the basis of $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

Does a orthogonal basis for the span of $S$ always have the same dimension as the basis of $S$

Basically if I have found the orthonormal basis for the span of S can I use that to find the dimension of the span of $S$. Or do I need to do a separate calculation... row reduction etc.?

Comment: Any two bases have the same cardinality (which means, in the finite dimensional setting, they have the same number of elements), and an orthonormal basis is, as the name says, a basis. So no, you don't need another calculation.

Comment: By the way, the phrase "dimension of the basis of $S$" makes no sense: a basis is not a vector space, so it does not have a dimension. You mean something like: does an orthonormal basis have the same number of elements as any other basis of $S$.

Comment: So @symplectomorphic if there are 3 elements in the orthogonal basis for the span $S$ the dimension of the span of S would be 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have an orthonormal basis for $S$. As long as you are definitely sure that the basis really is a basis for $S$, then **yes, that orthonormal basis has the *same number of vectors* as any other valid basis in $S$**.

Comment: "As long as that basis spans every single vector in $S$ and only those vectors": this phrase is completely redundant. That is what "basis of $S$" means.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I'm being redundant in order to be clear.

Comment: the redundancy here has the opposite effect: it misleadingly suggests a basis of $S$ might fail to span $S$, that there is something more to check. There is nothing more to check beyond the fact that the set is indeed a basis.

Comment: @symplectomorphic OK, I've changed it to "as long as you are definitely sure that the basis really is a basis of $S$".

Answer (score 4):

For infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, the term "basis" can have two distinct meanings. In the context of an orthonormal basis, infinite sums are allowed. However, in the context of a vector space basis (sometimes called a Hamel basis), only finite sums can be considered. Thus for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, an orthonormal basis is not a vector space basis. The cardinality of an orthonormal basis can differ from the cardinality of a vector space basis.

For example, the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ of square-summable sequences has a countable orthonormal basis, but every vector space basis of $\ell^2$ is uncountable.